# Animated texture coordinates not working

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsles, rajawali

I am struggling to learn GLSL ES so that I can offload a bunch of my animation from CPU to the GPU. My issue is with the creation of a simple animated shader that uses a sprite sheet. The shader does not use lights at all, I just show the full texture value to keep things very basic. My OpenGL ES framework of choice is Rajawali, so some of my values and parameters are pulled in from those classes.

When I use this shader with `isAnimated = false` the texture is applied as expected. However, when `isAnimated = true` the model is all black as if no texture is being applied.

I am able to confirm that the vertex and fragment shaders are evaluating `ifdef ANIMATED` as `true`, so it seems to be something with my texture coordinate modification that is causing trouble.

```
"       vTextureCoord.s = mod(uCurrentFrame, uNumTileRows) * uTileSize;" +
"       vTextureCoord.t = uTileSize * floor(uCurrentFrame  / uNumTileRows);\n" +
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my complete & non-working shader class:

```
package rajawali.materials;

import android.opengl.GLES20;

public class SimpleAnimatedMaterial extends AMaterial {
protected static final String mVShader = 
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +

    "#ifdef ANIMATED\n" +
    "uniform float uCurrentFrame;\n" +
    "uniform float uTileSize;\n" +
    "uniform float uNumTileRows;\n" +
    "#endif\n" +

    "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
    "attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;\n" +
    "attribute vec4 aColor;\n" +

    "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
    "varying vec4 vColor;\n" +      

    "void main() {\n" +
    "   gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
    "   #ifdef ANIMATED\n" +
    "       vTextureCoord.s = mod(uCurrentFrame, uNumTileRows) * uTileSize;" +
    "       vTextureCoord.t = uTileSize * floor(uCurrentFrame  / uNumTileRows);\n" +
    "   #else\n" +
    "       vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;\n" +
    "   #endif\n" +
    "   vColor = aColor;\n" +
    "}\n";

protected static final String mFShader = 
    "precision mediump float;\n" +

    "uniform sampler2D uDiffuseTexture;\n" +

    "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
    "varying vec4 vColor;\n" +

    "#ifdef ANIMATED\n" +
    "   uniform float uTileSize;\n" +
    "   uniform float uNumTileRows;\n" +
    "#endif\n" +

    "void main() {\n" +
    "#ifdef TEXTURED\n" +
    "   #ifdef ANIMATED\n" +
    "       vec2 realTexCoord = vTextureCoord + (vTextureCoord / uNumTileRows);" +
    "       gl_FragColor = texture2D(uDiffuseTexture, realTexCoord);\n" +
    "   #else\n" +
    "       gl_FragColor = texture2D(uDiffuseTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
    "   #endif\n" +
    "#else\n" +
    "   gl_FragColor = vColor;\n" +
    "#endif\n" +
    "}\n";

protected int muCurrentFrameHandle;
protected int muTileSizeHandle;
protected int muNumTileRowsHandle;

protected int mCurrentFrame;
protected float mTileSize;
protected float mNumTileRows;
protected boolean mIsAnimated;

public SimpleAnimatedMaterial() {
    this(false);
}

public SimpleAnimatedMaterial(boolean isAnimated) {
    this(mVShader, mFShader, isAnimated);
}

public SimpleAnimatedMaterial(String vertexShader, String fragmentShader, boolean isAnimated) {
    super(vertexShader, fragmentShader, NONE);
    mIsAnimated = isAnimated;
    if(mIsAnimated) {
        mUntouchedVertexShader = "\n#define ANIMATED\n" + mUntouchedVertexShader;
        mUntouchedFragmentShader = "\n#define ANIMATED\n" + mUntouchedFragmentShader;
    }
    setShaders(mUntouchedVertexShader, mUntouchedFragmentShader);
}

@Override
public void useProgram() {
    super.useProgram();
}

@Override
public void setShaders(String vertexShader, String fragmentShader)
{
    super.setShaders(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    muCurrentFrameHandle = getUniformLocation("uCurrentFrame");
    muTileSizeHandle = getUniformLocation("uTileSize");
    muNumTileRowsHandle = getUniformLocation("uNumTileRows");
}

public void setCurrentFrame(int currentFrame) {
    mCurrentFrame = currentFrame;
    GLES20.glUniform1f(muCurrentFrameHandle, mCurrentFrame);
}

public void setTileSize(float tileSize) {
    mTileSize = tileSize;
    GLES20.glUniform1f(muTileSizeHandle, mTileSize);
}

public void setNumTileRows(int numTileRows) {
    mNumTileRows = numTileRows;
    GLES20.glUniform1f(muNumTileRowsHandle, mNumTileRows);
}
```

}

Comment: If I try assigning same named uniform to both vertex and fragment shaders I'm getting an error "Uniform *** differs on precision". Could this be the case with your shaders too?

Comment: It doesn't throw any errors for me, which is what has been such a frustration! I wonder if that's happening because you don't have the super class which constructs some of those params.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you'e missing some '\n' newline characters on a few lines.  Though I don't think it's just this, it has created problems for me in the past if I can remember.

What are the bounds on the texture coordinates that you'll be sampling with (realTexCoord).  It looks like it could grow larger than 1 which for me has generally meant only the clear color would be displayed.

Comment: Bounds are the full texture sheet 0,0 to 1,1. I will double check the math thank you.